# Npm run build not creating build folder

Tags: reactjs, deployment, npm

I have a react application, and in the past I have successfully deployed it to surge.sh by running npm run build and then running the surge command from inside the build folder. I made one small change to the scss file, and now when I run npm run build, there is no build folder being created so I can't deploy the app. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: what change you did in SCSS file . Is npm run build showing any error ?

Comment: Please post the `scripts` section of your package.json

Comment: What if you only need the public folder? For example deploying on Netlify accepts the Public folder with a bundle.js file generated with npm run build.

Comment: I know this is years later, but Patrik Rikama-Hinnenberg that was the correct answer.